# iterating through texbox values using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a little procedure to prevent server side action if all texboxes do not have values.
I want to assign a color to the texbox for in case a value was not added.

This is not working the way I expected.

```
var txtName = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtName").value;
var txtSurname = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtSurname").value;
var txtContact = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtContactNumber").value;
var txtEmail = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtEmail").value;
var txtMessage = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtMessage").value;

var fields = new Array(txtName, txtSurname, txtContact, txtEmail, txtMessage);
var tot = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

    if (fields[i] == "") {
        fields[i].style.backgroundcolor = '#FEF5CA';
        tot++;
    }
    else {
        fields[i].style.backgroundcolor = "white";
    }

}
if (tot > 0) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

regards

Comment: What are you expecting? What does it instead?

Comment: Worth noting.  Your array contains strings, the values from your text boxes.  The strings do not have styles.  You need to have another array (or use JQuery) that contains your actual DOM objects so that you can manipulate their attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are creating an array of values, you need the elements themselves:

```
var txtName = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtName");
var txtSurname = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtSurname");
var txtContact = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtContactNumber");
var txtEmail = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtEmail");
var txtMessage = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtMessage");

var fields = [txtName, txtSurname, txtContact, txtEmail, txtMessage];
var tot = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

    if (fields[i].value == "") {
        fields[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FEF5CA';
        tot++;
    }
    else {
        fields[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }

}
if (tot > 0) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

You have to change `backgroundcolor` to `backgroundColor` and add `.value` to your if check.

Comment: he will be accessing the wrong attribute name too, add to your answer :)

Comment: @Edorka yep I made a few more changes to fix various issues.

Answer (score 2):

try `style.backgroundColor` instead of `style.backgroundcolor` (note the capital "C") Javascript is case sensitive.